# Why is my array turning into a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why is my array turning into a string?

I declared an array and tried to push on it:

```
  url = params[:img_url]
  job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  puts "addphoto==============================================b4"
  puts "job.photos:#{job.photos}-#{job.photos.instance_of? Array}"
  puts "====================================================="
  job.photos = Array.new if (!job.photos)
  puts "addphoto==============================================aft"
  puts "job.photos:#{job.photos}-#{job.photos.instance_of? Array}"
  puts "====================================================="
  job.photos.push(url)
```

Minus the `puts` all I'm doing is creating a new empty array if there isn't already one, then I push.

My logs say:

```
2017-04-05T17:51:41.034394+00:00 app[web.1]: addphoto==============================================b4
2017-04-05T17:51:41.034467+00:00 app[web.1]: job.photos:-false
2017-04-05T17:51:41.034490+00:00 app[web.1]: =====================================================
2017-04-05T17:51:41.034687+00:00 app[web.1]: addphoto==============================================aft
2017-04-05T17:51:41.034713+00:00 app[web.1]: job.photos:[]-false
2017-04-05T17:51:41.034715+00:00 app[web.1]: =====================================================
2017-04-05T17:51:41.035141+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
2017-04-05T17:51:41.036043+00:00 app[web.1]: 10 TID-ox2i47d2w FATAL: 
2017-04-05T17:51:41.036045+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `push' for "[]":String):
2017-04-05T17:51:41.036046+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/mobilevv/job_controller.rb:266:in `add_photo'
```

Why is my newly created array NOT an array?
I can't debug it because it only happens in my deployed server.

The exact same code throws this in my local server:

```
addphoto==============================================b4
job.photos:-false
=====================================================
addphoto==============================================aft
job.photos:[]-true
=====================================================
```

What is happening?

Comment: What's more important is how this relationship is defined. What does `Job` look like, roughly?

Comment: job.photos is a reference to all the job's photos via Active Record.  Why are you checking if one exists before creating an array?  If you specify the relationship correctly you can just add a new "job photo" without checking if any are there already.

Comment: Try handling the opposite to `!job.photos`.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Job` class? When it is throwing this error, does the instance of `Job` already have `photos` initialized?

Comment: yeah.. thats the right question to ask.. i just looked i my schema. photos is a text atribute of Job. thats my prob right there.. Thanks man.

Comment: Yup.. all right comments.. i was treating this as an object instead of an active record. This is more than enough. thank you guys.

Comment: I wonder about the difference between my local and heroku servers though.. im using pg on both.

Comment: If you save the record and then reload it later it will be coerced into a string.

Comment: In my schema the photos attribute is type :text, array: true. But when I create a new instance its value is a nil type string. Thats whats causing it.

Comment: I changed my data type, kept :text, array: true.. but gave it a default: [] now it gets treated as an array.. so that solves for new jobs. I still have to find a solution cause I have a lot of jobs under the previous schema. I'm going to close this issue as the title isn't making sense anymore. i need to reformulate my question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]", the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Because there is a lot of unknown information in the question we're having to ask for clarification. That's a strong indication it's not asked well. If the problem only occurs on one machine and not another, and the code is the same on both, then you need to compare the configurations.

Comment: sorry about that @the Tim Man, the question evolved on me. I was way off. I'd be batting blind without the clarification questions. So purpose was served.. :)